# Webpack remove file from watch trigger list, but reload its changed content

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've got a webpack project in which I compile a JSON based on content from other files as part of the build. I'm using the `extra-watch-webpack-plugin` to detect changes in these external files when using the `devServer`, but I'm running into a catch 22 with this setup. The updates to the JSON file are re-triggering a new build and causing the project to endlessly recompile.

I've tried adding the JSON file to `watchOptions.ignore` in my webpack config, but then the new content in the rebuilt JSON file doesn't appear when the recompile is complete.

Is there any way to ignore changes to the JSON file (or somehow avoid having them trigger a rebuild), but still have it's content be reloaded when the project is rebuilt?

Comment: Do the JSON file is separate file in your asset which is host by server? Maybe some small hint, please take a look what about browser cache. Maybe this is cached by browser with old content?

Comment: Could you give a (schematic) example of what you are talking about? Preferably with paths and steps included. I think your setup is correct, but the explanation is vague about how the JSON file should appear, how are you reading the content of this file?